# Django admin panel MEDIA_URL and db url

Tags: python, django, database, hyperlink, media-url

I've ported a website from a server to another few days ago. Now I need to complete the port, updating the database in the new server.

I've done it, but i get a strange error. It doesn't show me images.

In the database the image field contains `https://www.domain.ext/media/uploads/homepage/image_name.jpg` but in the admin panel the url is not like that, is like `MEDIA_URL` (set up in settings.py file) and image field from the database, so if `MEDIA_URL` is set up like `https://www.domain.ext/media/` , in the admin panel in the image field I'll see `https://www.domain.ext/media/https://www.domain.ext/media/uploads/folder/image_name.jpg`.

I've tried to amend manually the link in db leaving only `/uploads/folder/image_name.jpg`, I've refreshed the admin page and it seemed ok, but when I saved, it was another time in the wrong form.

Who is so kind to explain me why, and how I can manage with that?

EDIT:

Django Version is 1.2.5

Another issue i saw is that if there is `http` in `MEDIA_URL` the behaviour is the same as I have explained . If there is `https` the url become `/https:/www. ...etc...` . 
For this latter, I tried to put an `u` before the `MEDIA_URL` string, like `MEDIA_URL = u"text"` but it didn't work.

Comment: How are you creating/editing these objects?

Comment: From the db, do you think this could be the problem?

Comment: I don't know what "from the db" means. Exactly what are you doing? How did you create them originally?

Comment: Originally them was created using Django admin panel.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : Do you think that it's possible to exclude the `MEDIA_URL` from the admin panel, only for certain elements ? Or, in alternative, how i can tell to Django "these urls already contains the  `MEDIA_URL`, it's not needed that you add it" ?

Comment: Ok, now I got that the problem is not in the `MEDIA_URL` but in the string . I mean, if the string is like `http://www.domain.ext` it's all ok, and it works, if the string is with the `https` , so is like `https://www.domain.ext` . Django has problems and urls become like `/https:/www.domain.ext/media/http://www.domain.ext/media/uploads/image_name.jpg` . Any ideas ?

Comment: So you are saying that you can manually edit the DB to leave out the domain name from the URL, but when you re-save the model, it puts the domain name back in? Sounds like bad Form/Model code to me! I'd look at the form_valid() method to see what's going on.

Comment: The form_valid() method seems ok. It's possible that the reason is that  I'm using FileBrowser to select files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the problem!

The problem was in the `filebrowser` module.

In `filebrowser/functions.py` there is a method named `url_join` that was defined like:

```
def url_join(*args):
"""
URL join routine.
"""

if args[0].startswith("http://"):
    url = "http://"
else:
    url = "/"
for arg in args:
    arg = arg.replace("\\", "/")
    arg_split = arg.split("/")
    for elem in arg_split:
        if elem != "" and elem != "http:":
            url = url + elem + "/"
# remove trailing slash for filenames
if os.path.splitext(args[-1])[1]:
    url = url.rstrip("/")
return url
```

I simply added an `s` where there is `http` so now it's `https` and it works.
It writes the correct thing in the db and it also render the url in the correct way.

Thanks to all for help! :)

EDIT:

Merry Christmas to all! :)